# Network Connection Drops and Works Only After a Reboot [Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS]

Tags: networking, 22.04, network-manager, internet, ethernet

### Problem

The ethernet connection drops a while (unknown/random), and only rebooting the machine resolves it, until it breaks again after some time.

I have tried to monitor the network graph in the resources, which seemed quite stable for a while.

I tried re-installing the network manager, and also restarting the network service via `systemctl` command. However, nothing solves/reconnects me to the internet except a reboot of the machine.

### System

- Version: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Network Device Information

```
  *-generic                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: ff
       serial: 8c:04:ba:ff:da:1b
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.2.0-32-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=10.2.16.191 latency=255 link=yes maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d1104000-d1104fff memory:d1100000-d1103fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3165
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 79
       serial: 58:6c:25:cd:91:0a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.2.0-32-generic firmware=29.4063824552.0 7265D-29.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:128 memory:d1000000-d1001fff
```

### NetworkManager Logs

```
    Sep 18 00:37:19 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1694977639.7378] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 00:37:21 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1694977641.7650] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 00:42:42 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1694977962.1814] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 00:42:42 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1694977962.7644] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 01:03:03 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1694979183.1873] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 01:03:03 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1694979183.9583] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 02:03:12 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1694982792.4099] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 02:03:13 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1694982793.6696] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 02:38:22 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1694984902.6179] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 02:38:23 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1694984903.3588] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 05:08:31 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1694993911.8339] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 05:08:39 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1694993919.4743] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 06:03:59 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1694997239.1831] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 06:03:59 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1694997239.4811] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 09:19:19 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695008959.1817] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 09:19:19 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695008959.4735] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 11:09:28 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695015568.3779] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 11:09:38 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695015578.2686] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 11:19:44 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695016184.6021] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 11:19:51 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695016191.9013] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 12:15:12 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695019512.1791] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 12:15:12 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695019512.6801] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 13:50:32 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695025232.1795] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 13:50:33 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695025233.6975] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 14:00:39 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695025839.6100] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 14:00:47 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695025847.2554] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 14:51:07 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695028867.1783] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 14:51:07 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695028867.8964] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 16:01:27 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695033087.1799] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 16:01:27 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695033087.6749] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 16:06:36 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695033396.3779] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 16:06:40 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695033400.4501] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 16:31:47 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695034907.9940] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 16:32:22 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695034942.4423] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 19:12:25 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695044545.1460] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 19:12:36 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695044556.6742] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 21:52:56 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695054176.1784] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 18 21:52:57 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695054177.2390] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 18 23:29:47 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695059987.6791] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed new lease, address=10.2.16.191
    Sep 19 01:28:17 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695067097.1794] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 19 01:28:17 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695067097.6673] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 19 02:13:26 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695069806.3939] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 19 02:13:36 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695069816.5554] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 19 03:03:53 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695072833.1777] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 19 03:03:54 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695072834.7768] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 19 08:14:14 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695091454.1794] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 19 08:14:14 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695091454.7082] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 19 09:19:34 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695095374.1783] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 19 09:19:34 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695095374.7137] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 19 11:44:43 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695104083.3860] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 19 11:44:44 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695104084.5011] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 19 12:44:53 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695107693.5301] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 19 12:44:56 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695107696.7331] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 19 16:00:05 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695119405.8181] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
    Sep 19 17:52:29 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695126149.8728] agent-manager: agent[05207d0d06cbaab5,:1.90/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
    Sep 19 17:54:11 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695126251.6000] config: signal: SET_VALUES,values,values-intern,connectivity (/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (run: 10-globally-managed-devices.conf) (etc: default-wifi-powersave-on.conf))
    Sep 19 17:54:11 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695126251.6002] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
    Sep 19 17:54:11 username NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1695126251.6011] audit: op="networking-control" arg="connectivity-check-enabled:off" pid=49313 uid=1000 result="success"
    ---------------------------
    After sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
    
    Sep 19 18:35:42 varun-cvit NetworkManager[51547]: <info>  [1695128742.1363] agent-manager: agent[21e35eae2d9b0b1b,:1.90/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/>
    Sep 19 18:36:27 varun-cvit NetworkManager[51547]: <info>  [1695128787.1901] device (enp1s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys->
    Sep 19 18:36:27 varun-cvit NetworkManager[51547]: <info>  [1695128787.2107] device (enp1s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sy>
    Sep 19 18:36:27 varun-cvit NetworkManager[51547]: <info>  [1695128787.2108] device (enp1s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', s>
    Sep 19 18:36:27 varun-cvit NetworkManager[51547]: <info>  [1695128787.2110] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
    Sep 19 18:36:27 varun-cvit NetworkManager[51547]: <info>  [1695128787.2111] device (enp1s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
    Sep 19 18:36:27 varun-cvit NetworkManager[51547]: <info>  [1695128787.2115] manager: startup complete
```

Apologies if this is not the most efficient way to report my issues [Please guide with what is]. I'm struggling for quite a while with this issue now, and appreciate any help. Let me know if i'm missing any releavant information.

-> The problem is not only with the internet, but network in general. I'm not able to SSH into other machines in the same network. Also, the network i'm using is behind a CAS (Central Authentication System), however I use other devices on the same network, and they don't disconnect like this at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me worked installing the TLP UI tool and disabling the USB_autosuspend under USB settings

https://linuxconfig.org/introduction-to-tlpui-a-gtk-frontend-for-tlp

I see the tip in https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/upeqc1/network_keeps_on_disconnecting_on_2204/ on the last comment but didn't figure out how it relate to the network issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).